# How to find most recent file from a directory

Tags: linux, shell

I want to parse a log file which is in `/X` on a Linux server.
Below is the scenario :

- Log files are pushed into `/X` at a regular interval of 5 minutes or when a log file size becomes 5MB
- Now we are trying to make a parser which parses the latest created log file and gets the required information

How can I retrieve the file name of the most recent log file?

Comment: can you post a part of your log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Abhinav if you only want to get file name you can use ls -Art | tail -n 1 command in your script.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/X
for file in "${dir}"/*; do
    [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
    [ "${file}" -nt "${newest}" ] && newest=${file}
done

echo "the most recentently modified file is '${newest}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls -t` will sort files by modification time (in your case it's the same as creation time, since the files are written once), and `head -1` will give the first file, i.e. the most recent:

```
ls -t /X | head -1
```

A slight variation, which I think is more common, is listing in reverse (`-r`) and using `tail`:

```
ls -rt /X | tail -1
```

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth good to know. However, I doubt any of the reasons listed are relevant for OP